# On rpmbuild how to start without deleting the build content?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I'm making a rpm .spec for kernel.
If an error happen I have to correct and recompile the kernel (1 hour!)
Fast question: I want to start the build without rm -fr BUILDDIR
How to do?
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to avoid the deletion by changing the `%setup` macro to `%setup -D`. One reference to this behavior is [here](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/). However, if you're changing build parameters in the .spec you may wind up with an inconsistent build.

Comment: I know, is only for avoid to recompile the entire kernel if I made a mistake, then i remove the -D flag after correct the problems. If you add your comment as answer I can close this question

Comment: In addition to closing the question, consider accepting the answer as correct. Both helps future searches and adds to my reputation. :)

Comment: of course I made the answer as correct and also give a k+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the deletion by changing the %setup macro to %setup -D. One reference to this behavior is [here](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/). However, if you're changing build parameters in the .spec you may wind up with an inconsistent build.